# Android openOrCreateDatabase failed to change locale for db to en_US

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm opening an SQLite database in Android using openOrCreateDatabase. The method works fine on Nexus 10 with KitKat (and several other tablets) but fails on Nexus 9 with Lollipop with an error "failed to change locale for db xyz to en_US". This only happens if I try to open database in a public directory like Downloads. If I open using private context.getDatabasePath location, it works on Nexus 9. On all the other tablets both locations work. The reason I try to open in a public location is to be able to examine database with DDMS file explorer. Is there a way to create a database in the public location on Nexus 9?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this class. This will open your Database from any location you want.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Environment;

public class DataBaseHandler {

    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
    private static DataBaseHandler sDataBaseHandler;
    public static String datapath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "Your DataBase path";
    private AtomicInteger mOpenCounter = new AtomicInteger();

    public static synchronized DataBaseHandler getInstance() {
        if (sDataBaseHandler == null) {
            sDataBaseHandler = new DataBaseHandler();
        }
        return sDataBaseHandler;
    }

    public synchronized SQLiteDatabase openDatabase() {
        if (mOpenCounter.incrementAndGet() == 1) {
            // Opening new database
            if (mDatabase == null) {
                mDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(datapath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE | SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
            } else if (!mDatabase.isOpen()) {
                mDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(datapath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE | SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
            }
        }
        return mDatabase;
    }

    public synchronized void closeDatabase() {
        if (mOpenCounter.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
            if (mDatabase != null) {
                mDatabase.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it didn't work on Nexus 9.